# Can I specify the parent folder name instead of individual modules in the Tortoise ORM config_file?

Tags: python, configuration, fastapi, tortoise-orm

I am using the a json `config_file` with the Tortoise ORM setup.

This is a sample entry from the working file:

```json
"apps": {
   "my_app": {
      "models": ["my_models.users", "my_models.teams"],
      "default_connection": "default",
   }
},
```

`my_models` is the folder and `users.py` and `teams.py` are its files.

I would like to only have the parent folder `my_models` specified in the config file, and not need to enumerate all the sub modules under that directory (`my_models.users`, `my_models.teams` etc.)

On larger projects this could look pretty ugly, difficult to maintain.

The question is: "Is there a way to specify only the folder name instead?"

For example with a wild card, making the configuration element look something like:

```json
"apps": {
   "my_app": {
      "models": ["my_models.*"],
      "default_connection": "default",
   }
},
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?